# Combine two GCC commands / Make one Makefile out of two (QT and GCC Plugin)

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, makefile

I wrote a GCC Plugin which works very well. I created a Makefile which executes the following command to create the Plugin:

```
$ g++ -I$(INCLUDE_PATHS) -fPIC -shared $(SOURCE_PATHS) -o Plugin.so
```

I execute the Plugin with following command:

```
$ g++ -S -fplugin=./Plugin.so /TestProgramm.cpp
```

This works pretty well. Now I want to display a QT GUI when calling the Plugin. I wrote the GUI in Eclipse, so i got an auto-generated MakeFile. When executing the GUI, Eclipse executes following commands:

```
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I$(QT_INCLUDE_PATHS) -o debug/GUI.o GUI.cpp

g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib -o GraphGUI debug/GUI.o debug/main.o debug/GraphGUI.o debug/moc_GraphGUI.o -L/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib -lQtGui -L/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lQtCore -lpthread
```

GraphGUI and GUI are the classes of the GUI I wrote.

Now I want to combine these statements in my own Makefile, so that the Compiler compiles my Plugin and my GUI. I started working with Makefiles a few days ago, so I only got the basics about Makefiles. Hope somebody can help me.

Here is my Makefile:

```
GCC := g++
FILENAME := Explorer.so

GCC_INCLUDE := -I/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/plugin/include
QT_INCLUDE := -I/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/mkspecs/default \
              -I/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/include/QtCore \
              -I/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/include/QtGui \
              -I/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/include 

SOURCE_FILES = ## Some .cpp files for the plugin ##


$(FILENAME): 

    @$(GCC) $(GCC_INCLUDE) -fPIC -shared $(SOURCE_FILES) -o $@ $^

clean:
    @rm $(FILENAME)
```

I tried creating object files of the GUI and then include them in the command which creates the Plugin; like this:

```
    $(GCC) -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED $(QT_INCLUDE) -Idebug -I. -o debug/GUI.o src/Visualize/GUI.cpp

    $(GCC) -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED $(QT_INCLUDE) -Idebug -I. -o debug/GraphGUI.o src/Visualize/GraphGUI.cpp

    # /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/bin/moc -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED $(QT_INCLUDE) -Idebug -I. src/Visualize/GraphGUI.h -o debug/moc_GraphGUI.cpp

    # $(GCC) -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED $(QT_INCLUDE) -Idebug -I. -o debug/moc_GraphGUI.o debug/moc_GraphGUI.cpp

    $(GCC) $(PLUGIN_INCLUDE) -fPIC -shared $(SOURCE_FILES) debug/GraphGUI.o debug/GUI.o -o $@ $^
```

If i execute it like this, I get undefined symbol: _ZN11QMainWindowC2EP7QWidget6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE error. If I execute the two commands beginning with "#" too, I get "undefined reference to main". I just copied these commands from eclipse; I don't actually know what they are doing.

Comment: You'll need to show us your current Makefile. It's also better to show what you already tried, rather than asking others to write it for you.

Comment: That is a linker error, where exactly are you linking in your compilation? (Like the second command you have for creating GUI with all the `-L` & `-l` options)

Comment: Make can recursively execute make. You could create a makefile that simply calls make on two other makefiles.

Comment: How big is the makefile generated by Eclipse?